# Jquery берет старый элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Возникла проблема при обновлении страницы с помощью Ajax. По идее oldImage и newImage Это один и тот же элемент. Но jquery кеширует их и надо запрашивать его заново. Есть иной способб это реализовать?

```
var oldImage = $(mainClass.properties.image);
var newImage = $('#'+oldImage.attr('id'));
console.log(oldImage);
console.log(newImage);
```

Comment: добавлять к ссылке изображения `img.png?1`, не?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нет

Comment: Тогда дайте вывод `console.log()`?